# How to make a View's exposed filter value match the Context Filter term name provided in the View path?

Tags: views

In Drupal 9 we have a View of Nodes with a Context Filter (Has Term Name to Term ID) and an exposed Filter for the term (called Resource Type). I can go to the Views path (/downloads) and add the term name (/downloads/white-papers) and the results are filtered properly but the exposed filter does not reflect the "white-papers" filter and this shows "- All -" as the selected filter.

How can we make the exposed filter reflect the context filter from the URL?

[image]
[image]

Comment: Those are two completely different things. A contextual filter is not the same as an exposed filter, even when applied on the same field. To pre-fill the exposed filter, use HTTP GET parmeter like `mysite.com/view-page?MY_EXPOSED_FILTER_FIELD=MY_VALUE`

Comment: Yes, I understand but we wanted to use the main filter as part of the URL and not a URL parameter (for SEO reasons). I was hoping for some guidance on how to populate the exposed filter to match the URL path context filter.